# How to make Google Ads refresh on page change in Next 13.4.4?

Tags: next.js

I'm receiving the error: Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them.

It used to work on older next version, using pages directory.

Here is the code i'm using.

```
'use client'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const AdBanner = (props: any) => {
const pathname = usePathname()
const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    useEffect(() => {
      try {`your text`
        (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }, [pathname, searchParams])

  return (
    <ins
      className="adsbygoogle adbanner-customize"
      style={{
        display: 'block',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      }}
      data-ad-client={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADS_CLIENT_ID}
      data-adtest="on"
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
export default AdBanner
```